# Initialize unsigned char array in c

Tags: c, gdb

I have the following code that initializes an array of unsigned chars:

```
     unsigned char ultralightAtr[] = {0x3b,0x8f,0x80,0x01,0x80,0x4f,0x0c,0xa0,0x00,0x00,0x03,0x06,0x03,0x00,0x03,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x68};
```

When i inspect ultralightAtr in gdb I don't get the same values:

```
 (gdb) x/20x ultralightAtr
 0x7fffffffdd40:    0x70    0xdd    0xff    0xff    0xff    0x7f    0x00    0x00
 0x7fffffffdd48:    0x70    0x19    0xbd    0xf7    0xff    0x7f    0x00    0x00
 0x7fffffffdd50:    0x00    0xc7    0xfd    0xf7
 (gdb)
```

Am I doing something wrong initializing the array or is it something wrong with the way I am printing the memory content in gdb?

Comment: Could you post the relevant code and sequence of gdb commands you used?

Comment: *When* do you examine the array? Where is the array? Is it a local variable inside a function? Can you please show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your program? You don't overwrite the array anywhere?

Comment: You need to run the code to at least the start of `main()` so that the c init code has run and has initialised `ultralightAtr`. Have you done that, or are you running that immediately after loading the program?

Comment: debugging the array just after having run gdb works fine, apart for some format stuff (I use x /20xb)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both the address and the contents of `ultralightAtr` indicate it is a local variable with automatic storage (aka *on the stack*).  You probably examine its value with gdb **before** its initialization code is run in the function where it is defined.  Did you just set a breakpoint at the function address and issued the `x` command there?

If this array is not modified in the function, you can make it `static` so it is initialized at load time instead of every time the function is entered.

Comment: Yes, it is a local varable, sorry for not making that clear. Setting it static solved the problem. Thanks!